# CGI Perl - Load Javascript on load, but only on specific criteria

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi, onload

I have a form that is displayed only when a particular link is clicked, and the options for a number of dropdown menus are populated by javascript.

I need to run this javascript when the form loads, but I can only find examples where it is put in the  element and from what I understand, CGI Perl creates the  tag in the start_html function.

Is there a way that I can trigger a javascript function only when the form is displayed?

Edit: 
The Form has two rows of dropdown menus. the javascript populates the options for the second row based on the selectedIndex values of the first row. I want the second row to be populated based on the defaults in the first row when the page loads.

Comment: You used "load" and "displayed" as if they are synonyms. Probably best if you said what this JS does.

Comment: _"I have a form that is printed"_ - What do you mean "printed"? Are you saying you have a webpage which may or may not include a particular form depending on the link that was used to open the webpage, and you want your JavaScript to call the form population function on page load only if the form exists? Or is the form created dynamically after the page loads (from JS, possibly with Ajax) and you're asking how to call the function at that moment?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not explain very well. The first scenario is correct.  The form is included depending on the link used to open the webpage and I want to populate some of the dropdown menus with javascript before the user has changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JavaScript function that populates the fields is also included conditionally by the same logic that includes (or not) the form, then you can test whether the function exists and if so call it:

```
if (typeof yourFunction === "function") {
    yourFunction();
}
```

If your function exists all of the time (perhaps it is in an external JS file that is always included on the page) then give your form an id (if it doesn't already have one):

```
<form id="someIdHere" ...>
```

Then you can test whether the form exists and call your function to do the population:

```
if (document.getElementById("someIdHere")) {
    //form exists, so call:
    yourFunction();
}
```

In either case, the JS code that I've shown would need to be either inside an `onload` handler or in a script block that appears after the form, because JS can only manipulate elements that the browser has already parsed.

(If the function itself is defined in a script block that appears after the form, and is included conditionally, then you can just call it directly right after defining it.)

Comment: Ah thank you very much, that makes sense. The javascript is in an external .js file, so I will check that the form exists.

Comment: I've just realised that this prevents me from having a default value in the rows that I am populating, as the javascript overwrites the contents of the dropdown.
I'm just going to do the initial population in the perl code and have the updates in javascript. This means I will have redundant code but unfortunately I just need to get this done quickly.